# Parse query then state change after resolve

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-factory, angular-ui-router

I have a factory defined to make a parse call that resolves upon completion.

```
.factory('currentRestaurantService', ['$rootScope', '$q', function($scope, $q) {
    return {
        getCurrentRestaurant: function() {
            var defer = $q.defer(); // Create a deferring object
            $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();

            // Get restaurant for user
            var restaurantObject = Parse.Object.extend("Restaurant");
            var query = new Parse.Query(restaurantObject);
            var thisUsersRestaurants = query.equalTo("user", $scope.currentUser);

            thisUsersRestaurants.find().then(function(restaurants) {
                defer.resolve($scope.restaurants);
            });

            return defer.promise; // Create an Angular promise to be resolved
        }
    };
}])
```

I make the call in a resolve block in one of my states hoping to resolve before going to the sales page.

```
.state('dashboard.sales', {
        url: '/sales',
        templateUrl: './app/dashboard/partials/sales/sales.html',
        controller: 'DashboardSalesCtrl',
        resolve: {
            currentRestaurant: function() { return currentRestaurantService.getCurrentRestaurant(); }
        }
    })
```

I cannot figure out why this doesn't work. I have been banging my head against the wall for the past week and cannot figure it out. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject `currentRestaurantService` dependancy first before using it in resolve `currentRestaurant` function.

**Code**

```
.state('dashboard.sales', {
    url: '/sales',
    templateUrl: './app/dashboard/partials/sales/sales.html',
    controller: 'DashboardSalesCtrl',
    resolve: {
      currentRestaurant: function(currentRestaurantService) { //added dependency in function
        return currentRestaurantService.getCurrentRestaurant();
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: @Niraj you should inject `currentRestaurant` in your `DashboardSalesCtrl` controller first then you could use it..otherwise it would be undefined always.